# Path Gradient in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, system.drawing, vector-graphics, gradient

I am trying to create a vector graphic color wheel in WPF. I am currently calculating the positions and colors of hundreds of triangles and filling them with the average color value of their corners.

I would prefer to do something like this solution from WinForms:
http://csharphelper.com/blog/2014/08/fill-a-polygon-with-a-pathgradientbrush-in-c/

Is there a way to accomplish this in WPF?

Edit to clarify end goal:
I need a gradient that is
0xFF RED between -π/3 to π/3, and linear gradient 0xFF to 0x00 RED from -π/3 to -2π/3 and π/3 to 2π/3.

0xFF BLUE between π/3 to π, and linear gradient 0xFF to 0x00 BLUE from 0 to π/3 and π to 4π/3.

0xFF GREEN between π to 5π/3, and linear gradient 0xFF to 0x00 GREEN from 2π/3 to π and 4π/3 to 0.

In otherwords, an HSV color wheel.

Answer (score 0):

I created three overlapping gradients, 120 degrees from each other to get this. You may want to tweak some parameters:

Please note that the exact image in the link will require six of them, using secondary colors as well.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Ellipse Stroke="Black" Width="150" Height="150">
        <Ellipse.Fill>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#0000FF00" Offset="0.496"/>
                <GradientStop Color="Lime" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Ellipse.Fill>
    </Ellipse>
    <Ellipse Stroke="Black" Width="150" Height="150" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform Angle="240"/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
        <Ellipse.Fill>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#000000FF" Offset="0.504"/>
                <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Ellipse.Fill>
    </Ellipse>
    <Ellipse Stroke="Black" Width="150" Height="150" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform Angle="120"/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
        <Ellipse.Fill>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#00FF0000" Offset="0.504"/>
                <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Ellipse.Fill>
    </Ellipse>

</Grid>
```

Comment: The last gradient renders over the first ones. That is not the desired effect. There also doesn't appear to be a blend mode property on any gradient types to help remedy that.

Comment: You are right. I see that it is because my sample blends alpha only across the radius. It should blend alpha towards adjacent colors as well to get the desired pattern.

Comment: That's a bit more involved. I will try to post an updated sample.